# Custom Objects and Storyboards

Tags: ios5, storyboard, custom-object

Are Custom Objects (the little orange cubes) still supported when using storyboards?

Details: I was making a sample iOS App using storyboards and I added a custom object mapping a class which only had a button and a method for that button and I started getting strange errors. I removed this custom object and added the button and the method to the view controller class and everything worked as expected; this lead me to believe that something changed in the way custom objects worked when using storyboards, am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orange cubes only instantiate objects at wake-up.  They're not really meant to add views.  For example I use a few orange cubes to instantiate extra UIViewControllers and then I link them to outlets in my parent UIViewController.  This gives me a nice clean way to create a number of child UIViewControllers for the parent UIViewController.  It was pretty much the same as pre-storyboard IB as well.  If you wanted a view, the you would add the view.  If you wanted an object you could instantiate it by IB or manually in the UIViewController.

Hope this helps.